# How to get an ASP.NET WebSite to use the right assembly (File reference instead of path/GAC)

Tags: .net, msbuild, reference, jenkins

I recently started using Jenkins to ease application Development. I have an Asp.net website that I am trying to deploy using it.

Details about the build:

- The project is retreived from Visual Source Safe using Jenkins.
- Is is then compiled using msbuild
- Once it has been built, it is deployed to a test server.

The compile runs fine, no errors, no warnings.

When I copy the web application from the PrecompiledWeb folder to the test server, the application crashes when I perform certain operations. The exception I get is the following:

> ```
> Exception type: FileLoadException 
>     Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, 
>     Version=2.111.7.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or 
>     one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>     does not match the assembly reference. 
>     (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
> ```

However, if I copy the web application from the website's folder, everything works fine.

**Note:** All non-Microsoft assemblies are stored in a folder called Assemblies at the solution level. All references in the projects point to assemblies that foler.

Is there a way I can find where the conflict comes from so I can use the PrecompiledWeb folder for the deployment.

**Edit:**
It seems that I have more than one assembly referenced in my project, but I don't know how to get only one. I checked in the Object Browser, with My solution selected and I get the following
[image: Both assemblies in object browser]

It seems that the WebSite project is the one causing trouble (When I remove it from the solution, only the right assembly is shown in the Object Browser).

Answer (score 1):

Open the project file as XML and find the Reference in question.  Change it so that it doesn't have a strong assembly name, for example,

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.102.2.20, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken={SOME-KEY}, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

...to one with an unqualified name and a HintPath that points to the spot in your codebase where the assembly has been checked in,

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\Oracle\Oracle.DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

(of course, I'm just making up the details of these, not having Oracle)

Note that it doesn't matter if your current Referenc already seems to have the HintPath set up properly, if it has the strong assembly name then whatever is in the GAC will have precedence.

Comment: Well... I can't do that in a WebSite, you don't have a project file you can open as XML

Answer (score 0):

In your Visual Studio project, when you select at that DLL in References and look at its properties, is Copy Local set to true? If not the DLL might not be copied over to the output folder.

Comment: This is a website project so I can't choose copy local on a reference. In fact, adding a reference to the WebSite only copies it to the bin. When I look at the project in the property pages, the reference is not added there (my guess is that maybe it tries to use the GAC)